# Windows password reset issue cmd

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, password-recovery

I tried using this command

```
net user Alap
```

Alap is my acc name Please tell me what password does this command sets because i cannot login to my computer. I used this command to remove my password but it clearly didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Ishaan,

If you look at the parameters you have the following:

> ```
> NET USER
>       [username [password | *] [options]] [/DOMAIN]
>       username {password | *} /ADD [options] [/DOMAIN]
>       username [/DELETE] [/DOMAIN]
>       username [/TIMES:{times | ALL}]
> ```

So, try something like:

> NET USER Alap mypa$$word

Also ensure you run the CMD as administrator, not a local user.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
net  user "%UserName%"  MyNewPassword
```

Answer (score 0):

As Michael's answer said, you have to supply *some* password. If you don't put anything after the username, you just get a bunch of information about the account. If you want to clear the password, pass `""` after the username, like so:

```
net user alap ""
```